# JSON to Excel without overwriting file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am stuck with an issue and hope that I could search for some help.

I am trying to insert rows of information from several JSON documents. The problem is that every time the program is run, the previous lines are exceeded. It will thus only be a line with only information from a JSON document.

**This is my Python code:**

```
for k in range(1002,1005,1):
    link = baseLink + str(k)
    self.driver.get(link)

    res = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text

    #Convert it
    converter = c.list_comp({
        "f_namn": c.item("data", "name"),
        "org_nr": c.item("data", "organizationNumber"),
    }).gen_converter()

    prepared_data = converter([json.loads(res)])

    xd = pd.json_normalize(prepared_data)
    xd.to_excel('lista2.xlsx', index=False)
```

I have tried to learn about **openpyxl** and how to insert certain rows but with no luck.

I would really appreciate some help to get further with this project!

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: Define a empty list before for loop. e.g lst=[ ] , then replace the line prepared_data = converter([json.loads(res)]) with lst.append(json.loads(res)). Further outside for loop prepared_data=lst then  xd = pd.json_normalize(prepared_data)
    xd.to_excel('lista2.xlsx', index=False).... try it

Comment: @Vivs I need to use converter to get the JSON to work. Otherwise I'm receiving errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   lst=[] 
   for k in range(1002,1005,1):
        link = baseLink + str(k)
        self.driver.get(link)
    
        res = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text
        lst.append(json.loads(res))
        
    prepared_data=lst
    xd = pd.json_normalize(prepared_data)
    xd.to_excel('lista2.xlsx', index=False)
```

Try this it will work.

Comment: It worked but I do not want to implement all info. That is why I used convtools. Is there an easier way to select specific data from JSON? Is it possible to have customized headers?